# How to auto-install runlevel control for existing service/daemon?

Tags: dns, services, init.d, bind, runlevel

Need to install a service/daemon (in this case `bind9`, a DNS service) runlevel control, aka "rc" control (`/etc/rc*.d` and such). `bind9` came pre-installed on my 11.04 system, but without aforementioned runlevel control.

How to easily (and preferably automatically) install the rc stuff for "compliant" services/daemons in /etc/init.d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official way is to use [update-rc.d](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/update-rc.d.8.html). Default settings are usually good:

```
update-rc.d bind9 defaults
```

but if you need to, you can explicitly chose the start/stop runlevels with:

```
update-rc.d bind9 start 19 3 5 . stop 98 1 .
```

where 19 and 98 are the sequence numbers that determines their start/stop priority respectively and 3, 5 and 1 are the start/stop runlevels respectively. Runlevels exact numbering and meaning can be found [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/run-levels-intro.html).

Comment: Thx Avio.  +1, chkmarked.  Better answer than mine.  (Was gonnna say `sysv-rc-conf <service> ...`.)